# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Resource Not Found for url | Azure Cognitive Services Api

Tags: python, azure, api, http, http-error

I'm trying to send an image through *Azure Cognitive Service API*. I got this Error Message:
**requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Resource Not Found for url : https://myfirstpythonapi.cognitiveservices.azure.com/analyze? ...**

```
# Use the requests library to simplify making a REST API call from Python 
import requests

# We will need the json library to read the data passed back 
# by the web service
import json

# You need to update the SUBSCRIPTION_KEY to 
# they key for your Computer Vision Service
SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# You need to update the vision_service_address to the address of
# your Computer Vision Service
vision_service_address = "https://myfirstpythonapi.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"

# Add the name of the function you want to call to the address
address = vision_service_address + "analyze"

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function 
# There are three optional parameters: language, details & visualFeatures
parameters  = {'visualFeatures':'Description',
               'language':'en'}

# Open the image file to get a file object containing the image to analyze
image_path = "c:/Users/PC[enter image description here][1]T/Desktop/CallApi/Dodge.jpg"
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function
# we need to specify the subscription key and the content type
# in the HTTP header. Content-Type is application/octet-stream when you pass in a image directly
headers    = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
              'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function
# we use HTTP POST to call this function
response = requests.post(address, headers=headers, params=parameters, data=image_data)

# Raise an exception if the call returns an error code
response.raise_for_status()

# Display the JSON results returned
results = response.json()
print(json.dumps(results))
```

Please help me. I'm a noobie...

Comment: you are using both "analize" and "analyze". Also your provided path in `image_path = "c:/Users/PC[enter image description here][1]T/Desktop/CallApi/Dodge.jpg"` looks very weird and if this is some server sided code you cannot provide a path from your local system as the ressource has to be on the server not the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `vision_service_address`.

Like below,

```
vision_service_address = "https://<your_region>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.2/"
```

**Test Tesult:**

[image]

**Modified Code:**

```
# Use the requests library to simplify making a REST API call from Python 

import requests

# We will need the json library to read the data passed back 
# by the web service
import json

# You need to update the SUBSCRIPTION_KEY to 
# they key for your Computer Vision Service
SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = "03****e"

# You need to update the vision_service_address to the address of
# your Computer Vision Service
vision_service_address = "https://centralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.2/"

# Add the name of the function you want to call to the address
address = vision_service_address + "analyze"

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function 
# There are three optional parameters: language, details & visualFeatures
parameters  = {'visualFeatures':'Description',
               'language':'en'}

# Open the image file to get a file object containing the image to analyze
image_path = "E:\\MyCase\Dev\\Python\\faceapi2\\jason.jpg"
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function
# we need to specify the subscription key and the content type
# in the HTTP header. Content-Type is application/octet-stream when you pass in a image directly
headers    = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
              'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function
# we use HTTP POST to call this function
response = requests.post(address, headers=headers, params=parameters, data=image_data)

# Raise an exception if the call returns an error code
response.raise_for_status()

# Display the JSON results returned
results = response.json()
print(json.dumps(results))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! btw, this is my first stackoverflow question. @JosonPan , you answered that. Thanks!

Comment: @MalanBandara Welcome to SO, we can learn and make progress together here ^-^.